# how fetch a query that returns 2 results?

Tags: php, select, fetch

I have a stored procedure like this:

```
BEGIN
SELECT id, name
 FROM t1 WHERE p1 = p2 ;
SELECT image FROM t2 WHERE p3 = p4;
END
```

I can fetch the first result only. how can I get the second?

Comment: simply remove LIMIT 1

Comment: I want fetch the results of stored procedure in php. my problem is that how can I access to the result of second select in sql query

Comment: then just use join, no need two queries

Answer (score 0):

You have to options to do this.

the first one is to do 2 query

> SELECT id, name  FROM t1 WHERE p1 = p2
>
> SELECT image FROM t2 WHERE p1 = p2

the second options is to rewrite your query

> SELECT id, name, image
> FROM t1 JOIN t2 ON t1.id = t2.id
> ...